# conditional probability, die problem

Tags: probability

A fair die is tossed until the digit on the top face is found to be 1 or 6. Given that 1 did not appear in the first two throws, find the probability that at least three throws are necessary.

Comment: What happens if the first die roll is a six?  Why would we have thrown a second time?  Is the interpretation of this that the first throw is both neither a 1 nor a 6 and the second throw is not a 1?  Or do we roll a 6 for the first throw, do we roll the die one more time for little to no reason just to say we could see what the second roll was?

Answer (score 1):

If a one did not appear, there are $5$ possibilities, $2$ to $6$. If at least three throws are necessary, that means that we did not roll a $6$ on the first two throws. Thus the answer is $(4/5)^2=16/25$, the chance that we did not roll a six on the first two throws.